# Closing popup window by clicking close button in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to close the popup window that appears when I hit a particular url. Here is the "inspect element" window of that page:

[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i[@class='popupCloseIcon']").click()
```

But it gives following error:

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression
>   "i[@class='popupCloseIcon']" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError:
>   Document.querySelector: 'i[@class='popupCloseIcon']' is not a valid
>   selector: "i[@class='popupCloseIcon']"

Here is the url where popup appears: https://www.investing.com/equities/oil---gas-dev-historical-data
Once the url is opened through selenium, the pop up appears after a few seconds.
How can I click that close button?

Answer (score 2):

The popup appears after some time, so you need wait to solve this. And you have invalid selector : `i[@class='popupCloseIcon']`, please use `i[class*='largeBannerCloser']`

[image: image close]

Try the below:

```
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/equities/oil---gas-dev-historical-data')

try:
    popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i[class*='largeBannerCloser']")))
    popup.click()
except TimeoutException as to:
    print(to)
```

This is wait until 60 seconds maximum.

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Comment: The `*` in `i[class*='largeBannerCloser']` is not needed since `largeBannerCloser` is the full name of the class. A more CSS-like selector would be `i.largeBannerCloser`.

Answer (score 1):

As the pop up appears after a few seconds accessing the url https://www.investing.com/equities/oil---gas-dev-historical-data to to close the popup window you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i.popupCloseIcon.largeBannerCloser"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='popupCloseIcon largeBannerCloser']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First, "i[@class='popupCloseIcon']" is a invalid css selector locator, it should be "i[class='popupCloseIcon']". Second, there are four elements mapped to the "i[class='popupCloseIcon']", the css selector "div.right>i.popupCloseIcon" will help you to locate the target element